# How to select information from database that is day, week, month, year old?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I'm currently getting "top rated articles" by summing vote values from 'votes' table against articles from 'stories' table.

**Current PHP query:**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10") or die (mysql_error("There was an error in connection"));
```

**Database Structure:**

**stories table:**

[image: img1]

**votes table:**

[image: img2]

---

But I would like to know how to display information within different time periods. Say show top rated articles "today" "last week" "last month" "last year". Basing on article creation date **st_date** from 'stories' table. I just need those 4 (today, last week, month, year) different queries or parts that are responsible to get data within different time periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date1 = "TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(stories.st_date) = 0";
$date2 = "TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(stories.st_date) <= 7";
$date3 = "TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(stories.st_date) <= 31";
$date4 = "TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(stories.st_date) <= 365";

$query = "SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name WHERE ".$date1." GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10"
$query = "SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name WHERE ".$date2." GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10"
$query = "SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name WHERE ".$date3." GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10"
$query = "SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name WHERE ".$date4." GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10"
```

Comment: Hi on $date4 there are 365 days, does it matter if there are 366 days? I mean will it mess things up or is it fine? Thnx for awesome ans ))

Comment: According to http://www.compshack.com/sql-plsql/find-number-days-year: `ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y'),12)-TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y')`. I don't try if it works. Perhaps it's easier in PHP.

Comment: Be careful with "stories.st_date = CURDATE()" st_date is a datetime. CURDATE returns date only. The match won't work if time is different then 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories 
JOIN votes 
   ON stories.id = votes.item_name 
WHERE (
       (st_date BETWEEN (NOW(), DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
       OR
       (st_date BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY, DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
      )
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10")
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick correction to some of the answers above. I believe OP is looking for AVG() instead of SUM() since there could be 1000 votes with 1 value and 100 with 5, so to get top rated, you'd need AVG. To get "rated most often", you'd do COUNT(). SUM() by itself doesn't actually tell you much. 200x5=1000x1=300x3+100x1

If you change st_date to timestamp, you can also use timestampdiff in addition to other date functions mentioned in other solutions. Change DAY to MONTH or YEAR and the <7 to <1 for month/year or just leave as days and do 30/365

```
$query = "SELECT stories.*, AVG(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name 
WHERE abs(timestampdiff(DAY, stories.st_date, NOW())) < 7 
GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10"
```

Also, the above query gives you the highest rated articles that were created within your desired period. If you decide to to see highest rated articles within a period NO MATTER when they were created, change your where clause to match the vote date

```
$query = "SELECT stories.*, AVG(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name 
WHERE abs(timestampdiff(DAY, votes.date, NOW())) < 7 
GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10"
```

You can combine both article creation and the voting period in one query also.

Last but not least, you should change name of 'date' column to something else like vote_date. Date is a reserved word and it's not a good idea to use that for column name